# Windows Rundll32 (child process of DllHost) is crashing. How can I even identify it?

Tags: windows-10, crash

Windows 10 Home / "x64-based PC" / Dell XPS 13 9360

In Reliability Monitor, I have many "app failures" every day.  They go back all the way to 2017-12-04 without variation (the details below are identical), when I believe this machine was first used.  The problem is marked as having been reported (apart from problem instances in the past few minutes).

@magicandre1981 also suggested I open a [public problem in the Windows app Feedback Hub](https://insider.windows.com/en-gb/fb/?contextid=205&feedbackid=0ba56f23-335a-4521-99ff-40b56106e7c0&form=1) for some reason.

My question is:  How can I identify this?  What causes the crashes?  Can they be resolved somehow?

### Problem details

- Faulting Application Path:    `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe`
- Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
- Fault Module Name: Windows.UI.Immersive.dll
- Fault Module Version: 10.0.16299.125
- Exception offset: 00000000000ac885
- Exception code: c0000005
- OS Version:   10.0.16299.2.0.0.768.101
- Bucket ID:    ab5106f0b0020ee0d7e0c2d4f71642fb (1720589277589816059)

"Anti-virus" is installed (McAfee VirusSafe) and running with no alerts, no quarantined items, no significant logs that I can find. `sfc /scannow` gives the system a clean bill of health.

### Triggering the problem manually

It seems possible to trigger the crash by logging in.  This isn't what has been causing it in the past, because the machine doesn't usually have a user logging in and out (or even turning the machine on and off).

Process Monitor [allows to trace process creation and exit](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/procmon-track-process-creation-exit-time/).  Running it as a second user, I am able to see the crashing process:

- Command line: `"C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe" -localserver 22d8c27b-47a1-48d1-ad08-7da7abd79617`.

It's not really clear what this UUID is.  The `-localserver` option does not appear to be documented.  Google finds a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1175267/what-is-this-rundll32-instance-running/1180551), the only answer claims it is "Process Profiling Performance Analysis Program (Windows Performance Counter Program)".  Admittedly I can see that `profapi.dll` and `powrprof.dll` are loaded in this process.

- Parent process: DllHost.exe ("COM Surrogate").

Described as "[I don't feel good about this code, so I'm going to ask COM to host it in another process.  That way, if it crashes, it's the COM Surrogate sacrificial process that crashes instead of me](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090212-00/?p=19173)".

- Command line: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\DllHost.exe /Processid:{133EAC4F-5891-4D04-BADA-D84870380A80}`

This UUID in the parent's command line *can* be found in the registry. It is associated with the name "Shell Create Object Task Server".  Using the registry tracking in Process Monitor, I see `DllHost` loads `shell32.dll`, located via `HKCR\CLSID\{133eac...}\InProcServer32`).

=> I think we can identify this parent process, as shell32.dll / "Shell Create Object Task Server", and that it is part of the OS.

---

Both processes run as the user `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`.  This seems a possible venue of investigation.  What is the privileged part of the GUI software doing, that needs to be run in a separate process?

### Crash backtrace

After running `procdump -ma -i C:\dumps`, I am able to capture crash dumps.  (`procdump -u` to stop capturing).  The analyzer from DebugDiag is able to open them and run the CrashHangAnalysis:

> In rundll32.exe_171225_165805.dmp the assembly instruction at **Windows_UI_Immersive!CUserTileValidator::_SetReadOnlyCapability+1d** in **C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Immersive.dll** from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to read from memory location 0x00000000 on thread 0.
>
> The following threads in `rundll32.exe_171225_165805.dmp` are processing an inbound RPC call over LRPC to the `OLE54BFB094974A828ACE9FBFE5A353` endpoint:
>
> ( 0 )
>
> ### Thread 0 - System ID 4332
>
> - Entry point   rundll32!wWinMainCRTStartup
> - Create time   25/12/2017 16:58:04
> - Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.000
> - Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.000

---

> ```
> ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+14 
> ntdll!WerpWaitForCrashReporting+a8 
> ntdll!RtlReportExceptionHelper+33e 
> ntdll!RtlReportException+9d 
> combase!ServerExceptionFilter+71 
> combase!AppInvokeExceptionFilterWithMethodAddress+62 
> combase!`ObjectMethodExceptionHandlingAction<<lambda_76d9e92c799d246a4afbe64a2bf5673d> >'::`1'::filt$0+77 
> ucrtbase!_C_specific_handler+a0 
> ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+d 
> ntdll!RtlDispatchException+358 
> ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+2e 
> Windows_UI_Immersive!CUserTileValidator::_SetReadOnlyCapability+1d 
> Windows_UI_Immersive!CUserTileValidator::_GenerateLargeFromDynamicAndReset+23 
> Windows_UI_Immersive!CUserTileValidator::ValidateUserTile+141 
> rpcrt4!Invoke+73 
> rpcrt4!NdrStubCall2+3a5 
> rpcrt4!NdrStubCall3+e3 
> combase!CStdStubBuffer_Invoke+62 
> rpcrt4!CStdStubBuffer_Invoke+3b 
> combase!ObjectMethodExceptionHandlingAction<<lambda_76d9e92c799d246a4afbe64a2bf5673d> >+53 
> combase!DefaultStubInvoke+2d2 
> combase!ServerCall::ContextInvoke+492 
> combase!AppInvoke+99e 
> combase!ComInvokeWithLockAndIPID+55b 
> combase!ComInvoke+210 
> combase!ThreadDispatch+d4 
> combase!ThreadWndProc+e8 
> user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+2ad 
> user32!DispatchMessageWorker+19f 
> rundll32!_InvokeLocalServer+1b9 
> rundll32!wWinMain+168 
> rundll32!operator delete+2eb 
> kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+14 
> ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+21
> ```

---

> ```
> Inbound RPC Call:
>
> Protocol Sequence    ncalrpc 
> Endpoint OLE54BFB094974A828ACE9FBFE5A353 
> Source Process ID 1160 
> Source Thread ID 2624
> ```

PID 1160 is an svchost.exe instance for "RPC" and "RPC Endpoint Mapper", according to Process Explorer.

Comment: I would suggest: 1. Create the directory C:\dumps\ 2. Download procdump [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump] to the same dir.  In an admin command prompt run `procdump -ma -i C:\dumps`
Next time it crashes you should have a full process dump in C:\dumps\  Maybe you can make that available.

Comment: @Biswa The immediate parent of the Rundll32 process which crashes, is the DllHost.exe process.

Comment: OK, I will consider capturing a crashdump with a fresh boot & fresh user which does not have any personal information, as a next step. Hopefully I will have time to do so.

Comment: report the issue to Microsoft via Feedback hub app

Comment: @magicandre1981 technically that's not a report.  The crash report is already sent automatically, as described.  [I've posted one](https://aka.ms/S6tabl), but I think all it really lets is other people to vote *publicly* that they find this annoying. MS will already have stats on how many machines are reporting this.

Comment: @HelpingHand thanks for your great pointer.  I used procdump to capture a crash dump, and ran DebugDiag on it to get a backtrace.  Edited.  Possibly the crash is due to something called a UserTile which is specific to this user.

Comment: Is that based on a function name in the crashing stack? Happy to take a look if you need it.

Comment: @HelpingHand `Windows_UI_Immersive!CUserTileValidator::ValidateUserTile`, as per editted question.  The user's picture was appearing as the default user placeholder icon.  Setting a new image for the user's picture appears to have resolved the issue, so that logging in to the user no longer triggers this crash.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Good work on changing the picture.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What causes the crashes? Can they be resolved somehow?

Apparently, the crashes are caused by validating the `UserTile` of this specific user.

I believe this refers to the picture that is shown when you log in.  After setting the user's picture to an arbitrary image file taken from `Pictures/`, the crash was no longer triggered when I go to switch users and log in as the specific user.

### How can I identify this?

It looks like "Exception offset" is a code offset inside the DLL/EXE (i.e. avoiding the effect of relocation / address randomization).  So the crash location can be identified by "Exception offset" + the specific DLL/EXE contents -

- Fault Module Name: Windows.UI.Immersive.dll
- Fault Module Version: 10.0.16299.125
- "x64-based PC" (the 64 bit version of the DLL, not 32-bit "x86").

If you have debugging symbols for the DLL/EXE, you may be able to take extra effort to look up this location.   Use `procdump` as described to capture a crash dump. Open the dump with any debugger which supports the Microsoft Symbol Service, if the DLL/EXE is from Microsoft.  The names of the symbols are less likely to change over time (or different hardware platforms) than the numeric addresses.  A debugger will also show a full trace of the nested function calls leading to the crash.

- Symbolic location: `Windows_UI_Immersive!CUserTileValidator::_SetReadOnlyCapability+1d` etc.